# Using Fetch to Return GitHub User Data

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, github-api

Forgive the ignorance, I'm not great with JavaScript (yet).  I'm trying to fetch public user data from GitHub and display it on my personal portfolio.  Currently I have the code below:

```
 getData(url) {
  return fetch(url);
}
const userData = getData("https://api.github.com/users/userName");

userData
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) =>
    console.log("There was an error fetching the data: " + error)
  );

  console.log(userData)
```

The response I get is the JSON with the user data but when I `console.log(userData)` I get `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` as the response.

Also, I can see that there is an id in the initial response but when I `console.log(userData.id)` I get `undefined`.

I've read the GitHub API docs and watched a few videos on Promises but I can't seem to get my code to work correctly.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this and any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `userData` is a promise. your data should be `response`

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Thank you very much...one last question - How would I go about setting the information in the response to a variable that I can use outside of the response code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because userData is a promise. If you try using async/await (documentation is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)) you'll be able to synchronously get the data.

```
 const getData = async (url) => {
   try {
     const data = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/:user_name");
     console.log(data.json());
     return data;
   } catch (e) {
     console.log("There was an error fetching the data: " + error)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  This returns:`Response
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers {  }
​
ok: true
​
redirected: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
type: "cors"
​
url: "https://api.github.com/users/js-goose"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }` but I don't get any user data...am I missing something?

Comment: @JonathanSexton the above code logs a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response). User data is obtained by `resp.json()`, which parses the `Response`'s body into a way more friendly plain JS object

Comment: @NinoFiliu much thanks for the clarification - I ended up getting the code to work correctly after some refactoring.  Thank you again!